# is asp.net mvc + jQuery good fit for asp.net membership and complex GUI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-membership, mvp

We're gonna build a line of business app, and do it using asp.net membership for security.

What is your recommendation on building application that should be easy to maintain and as hopefully future proof? The idea being to have a really complex and customized user experience and hopefully basing it on existing third party components to save development time.

Is asp.net MVC and jQuery a good fit?

EDIT: Found third party components like http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new MVC project it includes the ASP.NET membership integrated by default. It works great, and as proven by this site (StackOverflow) MVC is proven for large scale applications.

Comment: Would you advice integrating with forefront identity server and AD for external apps or using the sql based repository for the membership?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC and jQuery are great technologies, however ASP.NET Web Forms and jQuery are also great technologies.  Neither is going anywhere anytime soon.  In addition, you could look at other solutions like DotNetNuke which would ease the complex and customized user experience and open the door to numerous third-party components as well.

Comment: I'm not sure why to use dotnetnuke cms system as a platform, what would it bring in comparison with asp.net mvc by ourselves or by third party? Sure, cms feature but its just a very small portion and there are probably tons of cms components out there...

Comment: There are a ton of CMS solutions on the market for .NET, but to have the ability of the door to get a wrap on content management as a user feature instead of a developer feature is quite beneficial. In addition, there are tremendous amounts of third-party ad-ons (snowcovered.com) and even themes to take a site from start to finish in no time.  This brings the focus on creating custom features and not reinventing the wheel for commoditized features like registration, subscription, RSS syndication, site search, etc.

Comment: Yes, but still, if you only need very rudamentary CMS feature like News and multilanguage help feature what is the actual benefit other than the fact you have to wrap your entire application(s) in asp.net webparts, sharepoint webparts or whatever the cms platform is using. Alternatively you would be building your stuff outside the cms which kind of makes it pointless anyway.
Adding stuff that is not needed just because it exists will just confuse end users and make the support cost higher with no added business benefits.